# Unable to decrypt text in file python

Tags: python, file, encryption, aes

```
def DecryptMethod(txt_to_decrypt, key):
    #ct = txt_to_decrypt
    f = open(txt_to_decrypt,'rb')
    ct = f.read()
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), 16)
    #decoded_txt = pt.decode()
    print(pt)
    return pt

testData = DecryptMethod("test1.enc",decrypted_key)
```

Within my `tes1.enc` the encrypted version of the text test1.
However, I am unable to decrypt. Everything was alright until
This part.

```
pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), 16)
```

> The above part will constantly show the error:

```
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

I've already checked multiple times, but this part constantly throws out this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What libraries are you importing? Where is "unpad" defined?

Comment: unpad is defined 
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

Answer (score 0):

Plaintexts and ciphertexts (input/output) can only be bytes, bytearray or memoryview. In Python 3, you cannot pass strings. In Python 2, you cannot pass Unicode strings

You can convert the string to bytes like this:

```
b = bytes(mystring, 'utf-8')
```

For more information, read these [docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html)

Comment: Printing out my ct gives this  result b'/QM9kmEdUMg7GVjmlnUd2Q=='.
I printed the type of ct, and it says that its in bytes

Comment: What is the type of the return value of `cipher.decrypt(ct)`?

If it's anything other than bytes, try converting it into bytes too

Comment: ct is in bytes, after I changed the cipher to 
 cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv.encode("utf-8"))
A new error about : Data must be padded to 16byte boundary in CBC mode arises.

As for, cipher.decrypt(ct) I am unable to get the type of it, since the program will stop working when it reaches 
pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct).encode(), 16)

Comment: For **MODE_CBC**, the `iv` must be 16 byte long. I am not sure how you declare your `iv`. It's not part of the code you shared. As for the type, I was suggesting you do something like `dec_ct = cipher.decrypt(ct)` and then `print(type(dec_ct))` before proceeding with your unpad function

Comment: Before encryption my data is 16 byte, but after I decrypt it, it is in 24 bytes.
Is there anyway that I can convert from 24 bytes to 16 bytes?

Comment: Before encryption my data is 16 byte, but after I decrypt it, it is in 24 bytes.
Is there anyway that I can convert from 24 bytes to 16 bytes?
`ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode`
This error will keep appearing after I change it to `dec_ct = cipher.decrypt(ct)`